# Inequality with $ab+bc+ca=3$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw

Let $a$, $b$, $c>0$ and $ab+bc+ca=3$, prove that $\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b+1}}\geq \frac{6abc+6}{a+b+c+3}$.

I have tried using Holder $\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b+1}}\geq \frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{cyc}{a+b+1}}$

Comment: Sorry for editing so much i am using my phone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works!

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, where $v>0$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, $u\geq v\geq w$ and by C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b+1}\geq\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a+1)}=\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)+3}=$$
$$=\frac{18u^2}{6u+3v}=\frac{6u^2}{2u+v}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{6u^2}{2u+v}\geq\frac{6(abc+1)}{a+b+c+3}$$ and since $w^3\leq v^3$, it's remains to prove that
$$\frac{6u^2}{2u+v}\geq\frac{6(v^3+v^3)}{(3u+3v)v}$$ or
$$\frac{u^2}{2u+v}\geq\frac{2v^2}{3(u+v)}$$ or
$$(u-v)(3u^2+6uv+2v^2)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: So we need to prove that $3u^3+3u^2\geq 2uw^3+2u+vw^3+v$

Comment: Yes, but $v=1$ and $w^3\leq v^3$. Thus, we need to prove that $3u^3v+3u^2v^2\geq2uv^3+2uv^3+v^4+v^4,$ which gives the last inequality in my solution.

Comment: Thank you. The last part i didn't know how to prove.

Comment: It's just factoring. it's $3u^3+3uv^2-4uv^2-2v^3\geq0$ or $3u^3-3u^2v+6u^2v-6uv^2+2uv^2-2v^3\geq0$ or $(u-v)(3u^2+6uv+2v^2)\geq0.$