# If $a,b,c>0$ and $ab+bc+ca=3$, prove that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^3+5}} \leq \sqrt{6}/2$

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $a,b,c>0$ and $ab+bc+ca=3$, prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^3+5}} \leq \sqrt{6}/2$.

My attempt was to use firstly AM-GM in the denominator, like $a^3+5 \geq 3a+3$ and the set $a=x^2-1$ but a lot of trouble occurred.

Then, I tried to use AM-HM, like $\sqrt{6 \cdot (a^3+5)} \geq ...$ but this didn't work either.

Any help?

I think it's completely obvious that if two problems have the same condition and are inequalities, are NOT the same.

Comment: Any idea? Please help

Comment: It suffices to show $\sum a^2/(a^3+5) \leq 1/2$, which should be easy enough

Comment: Yeah I know how this occurs with C-S, but how to prove this?? ( I mean $\sum a^2/(a^3+5) \leq 1/2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality with $ab+bc+ca=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612122/inequality-with-abbcca-3)

Answer (score 3):

Another AM-GM helps:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^3+5}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{3a^2-1}{2}+5}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{a}{a+c}\right)=\frac{\sqrt6}{2}.$$